# Set GLSL pixels of texture2D

Tags: glsl

I want to create a 2D plotter in GLSL (with SFML for window handling). I import an empty texture into the fragment shader via `uniform sampler2D texture` (which works). Then I try iterating through the `gl_TexCoord` and set the pixels a colour.

Doing this changes the colour to red

```
vec4 pixel = texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);
pixel = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
gl_FragColor = pixel * gl_Color;
```

However, this turns the whole thing red as well:

```
for (int j = 0; j < gl_TexCoord[0].y; j++)
        for (int i = 0; i < gl_TexCoord[0].x; i++)
        {
            vec4 pixel = texture2D(texture, vec2(i, j));
            if (i * 2 == j) // y = 2x
            {
                pixel = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
            }
            else
            {
                pixel = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
            }
            gl_FragColor = pixel * gl_Color;
        }
```

This is supposed to only colour the pixels that have coordinates where `y = 2x`.

I am not very sure whether I understood the idea of `texture2D` correctly or not. If this is not how to, than how do you change the pixel of an empty texture?

Comment: What is an "empty texture"? And why are you writing to `gl_FragColor` multiple times? What do you expect that to accomplish?

Comment: I am actually using sfml to handle window behaviours. To create an empty texture in sfml I simply invoked the function `sf::Texture::create(int, int)`. This probably creates an image with empty buffers. I want to iterate through the texture coordinates and change the colour of each texel if the y coordinate is twice the x coordinate.

Comment: That doesn't explain what *you* mean when you talk about an "empty texture". A texture always has *data*; even if you didn't put any there. If a texture does not have allocated storage, then it cannot be fetched from in a shader.

Comment: Ok, so I looked at the docs and it is written that the contents of the texture are undefined once the function is called. This they call as an "empty texture"

Answer (score 0):

```
texture2D(texture, vec2(u,v))
```

texture2D samples texels from the texture bound to sampler at texture coordinate (u,v).
It is an input parameter, you don't write into the texture. you write into the framebuffer.

The fragment shader main task is just to provide a color (RGBA) that will be displayed in the framebuffer (color texture) (the one that you see in the screen by default).

- If you want to create a texture using GLSL, you can use a framebuffer with a color(empty) texture. When drawing, you texture will be filled. See details here:

  [Framebuffers](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Framebuffers)
- Other option is to write directly in the texture from the CPU, without GLSL. See glGetTextureSubImage to modify a texture already passed to the GPU.

  [glTexSubImage?D](https://docs.gl/gl3/glTexSubImage2D)
- In your example, it could be easier to create a 2D array with the vertex colors and use it to fill the Texture with

  unsigned char* vertexColors= new char[width*height*4];
  // fill vertexColors
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, vertexColors))

  [glTextImage?D](https://docs.gl/gl3/glTexImage2D)